# AngularJS required field validation in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to follow the [AngularJS example](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input#example) of doing inline validations of required fields. However when it comes to using a `ng-repeat`, it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
  Me: <input required type="text" name="myName" ng-model="name" />
  <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.myName.$error.required">Required!</span>
  <div ng-repeat="friend in friends">
      Friends: <input required type="text" name="myFriend[{{$index}}]" ng-model="friend.name" />
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.myFriend[{{$index}}].$error.required">Required</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6eeGD/)

Any idea what I am doing wrong or what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do it that way. The input element does not like having the name dynamically generated. You will need to use ng-form as a subform and wrap the repeated element. Here is a fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p26VQ/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="myForm" novalidate>
      Me: <input required type="text" name="myName" ng-model="name" /><span class="error"  ng-show="myForm.myName.$error.required">
  Required!</span>
      <div ng-repeat="friend in friends">
          <ng-form name="subform{{$index}}">
              Friends: <input required type="text" name="myFriend" ng-model="friend.name" /> 
              <span class="error" ng-show="subform{{$index}}.myFriend.$error.required">Required</span>
          </ng-form>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: There is actually an [issue open for AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1404), where one of the comments has a [workaround](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1404#issuecomment-30861993). This worked a lot better for my setup.

Comment: For anyone else that comes across this, the issue is closed and name can now be dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0):

Using at least AngularJS 1.4.3 you can use this:

```
name="formControl_{{uniqueId}}"
```

And this:

```
ng-messages="myForm[ 'formControl_' + uniqueId ].$error"
```

*Taken from the comment at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1404#issuecomment-125805732 found in the issue referenced by Danny.*